# Failing to match string with disk serial in batch

Tags: batch-file

I've very little experience with batch, and right now I'm having a hard time comparing strings.

Essentially, what I actually want is to check if I have an external drive mounted and if I do trigger a command. I get all the drives serials and check if the one I'm expected is in the list:

```
:: I've tested with and without the EnableDelayedExpansion:
::setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
::setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set torun=wmic diskdrive get serialnumber /format:value
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('%torun%') do (
    ::set "serial=%%a"
    echo %%a
    set "expected=     ABCDEFG1"
    if "!expected!" == "%%a" echo Valid serial number!
)
```

When I run this, I actually see the drivers serials printed, and the one I want is in the list, but the if statement never triggers and I actually tried several different ways.
I've tried:

```
if %%a == "     ABCDEFG1" echo Valid serial number!
if "%%a" == "     ABCDEFG1" echo Valid serial number!
if /I "!expected!" == "%%a" echo Valid serial number!
if !expected!" == "%%a" echo Valid serial number!
if %expected% == "%%a" echo Valid serial number!
if "%expected%" == "%%a" echo Valid serial number!
```

And several other variations, sometimes the script run but doesn't trigger the `echo Valid serial number!`, and othertimes `I get echo was unexpected at this time`.

It's worth noting that in the `echo %%a` some drivers come with several trailing spaces before the serial, and **I've tried checking with both the spaces and without**.

*PS.: I've the correct serial in my script.*

Comment: Spaces are significant in `set` strings. Does it work if you use `set "expected=ABCDEFG1"` instead of `set "expected=     ABCDEFG1"`?

Comment: @SomethingDark As I've mentioned, I tried with both the spaces and without them, the result is unfortunately the same.  Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it differently:

From the [commmand-prompt](/questions/tagged/commmand-prompt):

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DiskDrive Where "SerialNumber Like ' %ABCDEFG1'" Assoc /ResultClass:Win32_PnPEntity 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "^_" 1>NUL && (Echo Valid serial number) || Echo Invalid serial number
```

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DiskDrive Where "SerialNumber Like ' %%ABCDEFG1'" Assoc /ResultClass:Win32_PnPEntity 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "^_" 1>NUL && (Echo Valid serial number) || Echo Invalid serial number
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to do it your way, via a `for` loop, don't use a standard list format, use a managed object format, which will omit any false leading space character(s), and make your comparison much simpler:

```sh
@For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DiskDrive Get SerialNumber /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @Set "DriveSerial=%%G"
@If /I "%DriveSerial%" == "ABCDEFG1" Echo Valid serial number
```

---

As a courtesy, here's  an example which more fully matches your submitted methodology:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "ExpectedSerial=ABCDEFG1"
Set "ToRun=%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DiskDrive Get SerialNumber"
For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%ToRun% /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do (
    Echo %%G
    If /I "%ExpectedSerial%" == "%%G" Echo Valid serial number!
    Rem Set "DriveSerial=%%G"
    Rem SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Rem If /I "%ExpectedSerial%" == "!DriveSerial!" Echo Valid serial number^^!
    Rem EndLocal
)
Pause
```

You'll note that I have correctly used `Rem` to comment my code. You should not use a broken label, *(`::`)*, as a comment, especially when that can often fail within a parenthesized block of code. Please remark and unremark the lines as needed.